# Google Admob banner below Navigation toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Below is my Activity_main.xml file

**Activity_Main.xml Screenshot**

[image]

In my Android App Main Activity Layout, Google Admob is placed at below Top App Bar, and i want to switch the Admob banner to below Navigation Banner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/parent_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbar_main_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/container_admob"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#00ffffff"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/adView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            ads:adSize="BANNER"
                            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

                        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey_3"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_body"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_bottom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state_primary_2"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/color_state_primary_2"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_bottom" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my Android App Main Activity Layout, Google Admob is placed at below Top App Bar, and i want to switch the Admob banner to below Navigation Banner.Please help me to resolve this, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: in your activity_main.xml file make the parent layout as the relative and insdie put the Navigation view and Add view , give the add view propery align parent bottom and layout above property (give id of addview) in your navigation view make, it is better if you post your xml code

Comment: pest your whole xml file here in your post

Comment: Hi Navin, Inserted code in the post, Please review!

Comment: Can anyone help me further, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, put your AdView below BottomNavigationView and remove android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" from BottomNavigationView and add another property layout above(with id adView)

Comment: Can you please help me with the code,  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need app customization, If anyone interested please Email me at boloapp.in@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

remove addview from linear layout and replace the code below

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state_primary_2"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/color_state_primary_2"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_bottom" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I tried the above. Admob banner is displaying right below Nav Bar. But having some issues. Like Admob container, is not displaying below admob banner.

Comment: I tried SMART_BANNER to overcome, but still background is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this::

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId=".....">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Hi Suvidha, I have tried to but not working perfectly!.

Comment: I need app customization, If anyone interested please Email me at boloapp.in@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Just add that line in your bottom navigation View:

app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView"